# MySQL, concat by join table with in clauses

Tags: mysql, concatenation

Is there any way to join two tables and get `group_concat`?
I have two tables, the 1st one with `id` and `name` with the following data:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Mark |
| 3 | Helen |
| 4 | Simon |

and the 2nd table with the following data:

| id | day | team | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mon | 2,4 | 100.00 |
| 2 | mon | 1,4 | 80.00 |
| 3 | fri | 2,3 | 150.00 |
| 4 | sun | 1,3,4 | 120.00 |
| 5 | wen | 3 | 40.00 |

the `team` field has members ids in comma separated string.

How to concatenate the names, separated by commas in one column?

Required result:

| id | day | team | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mon | Mark, Simon | 100.00 |
| 2 | mon | John, Simon | 80.00 |
| 3 | fri | Mark, Helen | 150.00 |
| 4 | sun | John, Helen, Simon | 120.00 |
| 5 | wen | Helan | 40.00 |

I tried `group_concat` like the following code, but it did not work:

```
select b.*, (select group_concat(a.name separeted ',')
from a where a.id in (b.team)) as teamname from b
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FIND_IN_SET` instead of `IN`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE a
>     (`id` int, `name` varchar(5))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO a
>     (`id`, `name`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'John'),
>     (2, 'Mark'),
>     (3, 'Helen'),
>     (4, 'Simon')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE b
>     (`id` int, `day` varchar(3), `team` varchar(5), `amount` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO b
>     (`id`, `day`, `team`, `amount`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'mon', '2,4', 100.00),
>     (2, 'mon', '1,4', 80.00),
>     (3, 'fri', '2,3', 150.00),
>     (4, 'sun', '1,3,4', 120.00),
>     (5, 'wen', '3', 40.00)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> select 
> b.*
> , (select group_concat(a.name ) 
> from a 
> where FIND_IN_SET(a.id, b.team) > 0) as teamname 
> from b
> ```
>
> ```
> id | day | team  | amount | teamname        
> -: | :-- | :---- | -----: | :---------------
>  1 | mon | 2,4   |    100 | Mark,Simon      
>  2 | mon | 1,4   |     80 | John,Simon      
>  3 | fri | 2,3   |    150 | Mark,Helen      
>  4 | sun | 1,3,4 |    120 | John,Helen,Simon
>  5 | wen | 3     |     40 | Helen
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d625afa7f443994cda93df9b9eede7f9)*